# How to jump to a specific date on fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I've created a page where all the booked appointments showing in a table with four buttons for each one, **show on calendar**, **edit**, **delete** and **not_accepted** .

The edit, delete and not_accepted buttons i can handle them very easily, but i don't know how to show the clicked event on the calendar which exist under the table, lets imagine that i clicked **show on calendar** on one of the booked appointments the page will be scrolled down a little bit and the calendar should took me to the event, so its similar to a slider but i don't have to click next to see where is the event exist by date for example .

I am feeling that `jsEvent coordinates` would help some how !!, but really don't know how to do it .

Please any help .

Comment: firstly you would want https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/ to put the calendar onto the correct date for the appointment. After that you can use the general jQuery "scrollTo" function to scroll down to the calendar div. You can't target a specific event on the calendar but you can use the view settings to ensure that the event is likely to be visible (minTime, maxTime, height, that kind of thing - have a read of the documentation).

Comment: So outside the calendar i can't target a specific event by just clicking a button , am i right ? , maybe i can load a new calendar with the new data by clicking a button, so if gotoDate takes a **date** i can use `$(this).val` to take the date and to put it inside , is that possible ?

Comment: not easily no because the HTML elements that are used by fullCalendar to draw the events don't appear to have any unique identifiers on them. You can see this by inspecting the elements on any of the demos on the fullCalendar website.

Comment: " takes a date i can use $(this).val to take the date and to put it inside , is that possible" Put it inside what? The date on its own does not identify the specific event.

Comment: No i meant by that , for example, i can give the table rows an attribute calls `data-date='THE DATE'` and by clicking the button i can take the attribute value as a variable and to initiate a new calendar with new values including the date so it will be something like : `var Date = $(this).attr('data-date')` then `.fullcalendar('gotoDate', Date)` .

Comment: that's the general idea, but you don't need to initialise a new calendar every time. Load the calendar once when your page loads, with all the events already in it. Then use goToDate and scrollTo to position the calendar and the browser in the right place.

Comment: Yep, i will give that a try !!

Comment: I want to mention that it worked as it should be , if i clicked any event , the calendar tooks me to the clicked date , thanks dude as always for your interests , most of answers cames from you , so a big thanks :) .